# Cube database renamed - where is it logged?

Tags: windows, ssas, ssas-tabular

Over the weekend someone renamed one of the cube databases that we have leading to massive headaches and SQL job failures. I would like to know if a cube database rename action is logged anywhere and related details. I tried replicating the same in development environment and searching in `eventvwr`, without much luck. Any leads will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The key mechanisms for maintaining error logs for Analysis Services are to either:

```
1.Keep track of the data stored in the msmdsrv.log.
 It will be necessary to copy the log off before it gets overwritten.
2.If you are using Analysis Services 2005, 2008, or 2008 R2, 
you can generate your own trace events as noted in the System-wide 
Trace file section of the post Analysis Services Processing Best Practces
 at: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966525.aspx#EBAA
3.If you are using SQL Server 2012, 
you can use the XEvents feature as noted in the SSAS documentation Use SQL Server Extended Events (XEvents) to Monitor Analysis Services at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492139.aspx
```

by using the above mechinisims ,you can keep track of log going forward